# Почему вылетает ошибка при создании компонент Delphi

Tags: delphi

Создал функции, в которых создаю компонент, читаю из базы, а потом уничтожаю, делаю так, потому что, функции вызываются потоками. все работает какое то неопределённое время, а потом вылетает ошибка.

Скажите, что я не так делаю? Все функции выделены в отдельный Unit13

Пример 2-х функций:

```
class function RGetInfo.GetGroups(Player: String): XGroups;
var
  iStrig: String;
  FDConnection: TFDConnection;
  FDQuery: TFDQuery;
begin
  try
    FDConnection := TFDConnection.Create(Form1);
    with FDConnection do
    begin
      Params.Add('Database=asd');
      Params.Add('DriverID=MySQL');
      Params.Add('Password=123456');
      Params.Add('Server=localhost');
      Params.Add('User_Name=root');
      Params.Add('CharacterSet=utf8');
      Params.Add('ReadTimeout=100');
      Connected := True;
    end;
  except

  end;
  try
    FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create(Form1);
    FDQuery.Connection := FDConnection;
  except

  end;
    try
      FDQuery.SQL.Clear;
      FDQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT `name` FROM `880102` WHERE `active` = "1"');
      FDQuery.Open;
        while not FDQuery.Eof do
        begin
          iStrig := iStrig + '"' + FDQuery.FieldByName('name').AsString + '",';
          FDQuery.Next;
        end;
        Delete(iStrig, length(iStrig), 1);
        Result.withError := False;
      FDQuery.Close;
    except
      iStrig := '"all"';
      Result.withError := True;
    end;
  Result.xText := iStrig;
  try FDQuery.Destroy; except end;
  try FDConnection.Destroy; except end;
end;

class function RGetInfo.GetLanguages(Player: String): XLanguages;
var
  iStrig: String;
  FDConnection: TFDConnection;
  FDQuery: TFDQuery;
begin
  try
    FDConnection := TFDConnection.Create(Form1);
    with FDConnection do
    begin
      Params.Add('Database=asd');
      Params.Add('DriverID=MySQL');
      Params.Add('Password=123456');
      Params.Add('Server=localhost');
      Params.Add('User_Name=root');
      Params.Add('CharacterSet=utf8');
      Params.Add('ReadTimeout=100');
      Connected := True;
    end;
  except

  end;
  try
    FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create(Form1);
    FDQuery.Connection := FDConnection;
  except

  end;
    try
      FDQuery.SQL.Clear;
      FDQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT `name` FROM `880103` WHERE `active` = "1"');
      FDQuery.Open;
        while not FDQuery.Eof do
        begin
          iStrig := iStrig + '"' + FDQuery.FieldByName('name').AsString + '",';
          FDQuery.Next;
        end;
        Delete(iStrig, length(iStrig), 1);
        Result.withError := False;
      FDQuery.Close;
    except
      iStrig := '"en"';
      Result.withError := True;
    end;
  Result.xText := iStrig;
  try FDQuery.Destroy; except end;
  try FDConnection.Destroy; except end;
end;
```

Comment: это потому что юнит 13й :D

Comment: зачем вы вообще постоянно создаете коннекты? Создайте его один раз и пользуйте, или создайте пул коннектов, если они различаются. Запросы если интенсивно используются, тоже смысла нет каждый раз создавать (если объект живет дольше чем один вызов функции).
Для освобождения объектов обыкновенно используется `Free` а не прямой вызов `Destroy`. Про именование типов данных я вам уже писал в прошлый раз, общепринято начинать с `T`, а не `X` или еще что-нибудь.  

По итогу, с какой ошибкой падает программа, начинать надо с этого. `AV` или что-то другое?

Comment: unit1 добавлен
implementation

uses
  Engin;

Comment: строки настроек подключения вынесите в константы класса. чтобы не искать их по коду для изменения. Про `Owner`-а вам уже сказали. Использование пустых `except`  это не очень хорошо, ибо просто скрывает ошибку и игнорирует ее. Помимо `except` есть еще и `finally`.

Comment: да AV. Про Т я помню новые типы называю так, не стал переписывать старое, это критично? Free сейчас попробую.а на счет создать один раз и пользоваться, когда был 1 компонент вылетало что запрос не может быть осуществлен так как предыдущий не закончен, функции вызываются клиентом каждые 2-3 секунды, и неопределенное количество клиентов за раз могут вызывать одну и ту же функцию

Comment: планирую логирование ошибок, для этого except

Comment: @teran названия типов типа type  RMake = class, который содержит в себе функции class function, тоже надо с Т начинать?

Comment: ВЫ. конечно, можете не следовать общепринятым подходам к именованию, но принято называть все классы и структуры с префикса `T` (T-type/user-type). Исключением часто являются классы rtti-атрибутов, там не используют префикс. Аналогично интерфейсы начинают с `I` (I - Interface), поля с `F` (F - field) и так т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как функции выполняются в потоках, дело, вероятно, в том, что происходят одновременные обращения к форме `Form1` из второстепенных потоков.

Вам нет никакого смысла передавать какую-либо форму в качестве владельца в конструкторы компонент. Вы сами контролируете время жизни компонент, только не совсем правильно.

```
FDConnection := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
try
  ...
  FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    ...
  finally
    FDQuery.Free;
  end;
finally
  FDConnection.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Только если в такой конструкции не обработать ошибку в потоке, то приложение вылетит на первом же exception'е.